# Change value of TextView on Item Click inside a RecyclerView?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

I am developing an app for restaurant management, but stuck at a point where i need to update value of textview(outside of RecyclerView) on item click inside the RecyclerView.

This is my adapter, Consider a textView outside this adapter and set a value on item click of Plus and Minus ImageViews as shown in below code...

```
public class MyRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyRecyclerAdapter.MyHolder> {

ArrayList<MenuItem> MenuDetailList;
Typeface font;

public MyRecyclerAdapter(ArrayList<MenuItem> MenuDetailArray){
    this.MenuDetailList = MenuDetailArray;
}

@Override
public MyRecyclerAdapter.MyHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_menu_row_item, null);
    return new MyHolder(v);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final MyRecyclerAdapter.MyHolder holder, final int position) {

    holder.txtSubMenuTitle.setText(MenuDetailList.get(position).getTitle());
    holder.txtSubMenuPrice.setText(MenuDetailList.get(position).getPrice());
    holder.txtSubMenuCount.setText(""+MenuDetailList.get(position).getItemCount());
    setCustomTypeface(holder.txtSubMenuTitle, font);
    setCustomTypeface(holder.txtSubMenuPrice,font);

    holder.ImgViewSubMenuMinus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //holder.OrderCount = Integer.parseInt(holder.txtSubMenuCount.getText().toString());
            int ItemCount = MenuDetailList.get(position).getItemCount();
            if (ItemCount > 0) {
                ItemCount = ItemCount - 1;
                holder.txtSubMenuCount.setText("" + ItemCount);
                MenuDetailList.get(position).setItemCount(ItemCount);
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }
    });

    holder.ImgViewSubMenuPlus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //holder.OrderCount = Integer.parseInt(holder.txtSubMenuCount.getText().toString());

            int ItemCount = MenuDetailList.get(position).getItemCount();
            if (ItemCount < 20) {
                ItemCount = ItemCount + 1;
                holder.txtSubMenuCount.setText("" + ItemCount);
                MenuDetailList.get(position).setItemCount(ItemCount);
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
    });
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return MenuDetailList.size();
}

public static class MyHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView txtSubMenuTitle;
    TextView txtSubMenuPrice;
    ImageView ImgViewSubMenuMinus;
    ImageView ImgViewSubMenuPlus;
    TextView txtSubMenuCount;

    private MyHolder(View row) {
        super(row);
        this.txtSubMenuTitle = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.list_txt_sub_menu_title);
        this.txtSubMenuPrice = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.list_txt_sub_menu_price);
        this.txtSubMenuCount = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.list_txt_sub_menu_count);
        this.ImgViewSubMenuMinus = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.list_img_sub_menu_minus);
        this.ImgViewSubMenuPlus = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.list_img_sub_menu_plus);
    }
}
private void setCustomTypeface(TextView textView, Typeface font) {
    textView.setTypeface(font);
}
}
```

Thanks in advance...

Comment: It's not clear what are you asking

Comment: I am hving a textView outside my recyclerview, and having two buttons inside the recyclerview(listview) where i would either add or deduct items.
Now on adding or deducting items there is a textview(having item count) outside the Recycler view would be updated.

Hope that makes sense, due to confidentiality i can't post the screenshot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.In your activity initialize the TextView

```
TextView myTextview = (TextView) findViewByItd(R.id.textView);
```

2.Add a parameter TextView in the Adapter's constructor

3.Pass the TextView to the adapter

`MyRecyclerAdapter adapter = new MyRecyclerAdapter(menu, myTextView);`

4.Manipulate it as you want

```
ArrayList<MenuItem> MenuDetailList;
Typeface font;
TextView mTextView;

public MyRecyclerAdapter(ArrayList<MenuItem> MenuDetailArray, TextView tv){
     this.MenuDetailList = MenuDetailArray;
     mTextView = tv;
}
```

`mTextView.setText("Eat more pizza");`

Answer (score 6):

Accepted answer is a hack. That is not the right way to do it. You can create an interface to pass your click event to your activity.

Create this interface in your adapter class.

```
public interface OnItemClickListener {
  void onItemClick(View view, int position, String tag);
}
```

Then create an instance on class level of adapter.

```
private OnItemClickListener mItemClickListener;
```

and a method to set this listener.

```
public void setOnItemClickListener(final OnItemClickListener mItemClickListener) {
   this.mItemClickListener = mItemClickListener;
}
```

Now in your activity do this.

```
AdapterClassName.OnItemClickListener onItemClickListener = new AdapterClassName.OnItemClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onItemClick(View view, int position, String tag) {

    //Do whatever you want to do on item click in your activity

   }
}
mAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(onItemClickListener);
//mAdapter is your adapter instance
```

then last thing set click listener on your viewholder. I'm assuming your viewholder is present in adapter class only.

```
public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

  public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
    RelativeLayout mainHolder = (RelativeLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.main_holder);
    mainHolder.setOnClickListener(this);
  }

   @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
      if(mItemClickListener != null) {
        mItemClickListener.onItemClick(itemView, getAdapterPosition(), itemView.getText().toString());
      }
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

set tag onCreateViewHolder() that is your holder:

```
MyHolder holder = new MyHolder(v);
v.setTag(holder);
return holder;
```

Now you can get the data in your click listener:

```
MyHolder holder = (MyHolder)v.getTag();
```

Comment: HI, Gavriel, above answer works with small change.That change I am editing.

Answer (score 0):

One silly sollution is to try to pass the text view to the adapter when you declare it in your activity. Of course the text view should be defined before passing. Thus, you have to add a new member to your adapter, which is of type **TextView**, and you have to add a parameter of type **TextView** to your adapter constructor.....
I hope this trick can help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the concept of interfaces in this case. Lets take an example. Lets say textview is in activity and the instance of adapter is created inside it and adapter is set to recycler view

```
public class MyRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyRecyclerAdapter.MyHolder> {

        ArrayList<MenuItem> MenuDetailList;
        Typeface font;
        MyInterface myinterface;

        public MyRecyclerAdapter(ArrayList<MenuItem> MenuDetailArray, MyInterface myinterface){
            this.MenuDetailList = MenuDetailArray;
            this.myinterface = myinterface;
        }
```

Now in your holder you need to add onClickholder method  :

```
public static class MyHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView txtSubMenuTitle;
    TextView txtSubMenuPrice;
    ImageView ImgViewSubMenuMinus;
    ImageView ImgViewSubMenuPlus;
    TextView txtSubMenuCount;
    private final View holderView;

    private MyHolder(View row) {
        super(row);
        // save this view
        holderView = row;
        this.txtSubMenuTitle = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.list_txt_sub_menu_title);
        this.txtSubMenuPrice = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.list_txt_sub_menu_price);
        this.txtSubMenuCount = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.list_txt_sub_menu_count);
        this.ImgViewSubMenuMinus = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.list_img_sub_menu_minus);
        this.ImgViewSubMenuPlus = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.list_img_sub_menu_plus);
    }
}
```

Now in your onBindViewHolder set clicklistener on this method:

```
holder.onClickHolder(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
        myinterface.myMethod("I want to return string");
      }
    });
```

Now your activity must implement this interface. hence it will call myMethod inside your activity. Now you can do whatever you want to do in your activity. Add as many methods you want in interface and enjoy the callbacks. 
This explains power of interfaces.